# Best practice for filtering ICollection for a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `View` whose `Model` contains a `ICollection` which contains a set of filenames.

I have several areas on the `View` in which I want to list these filenames. however, depending on the area of the `View`, I only want certain types of files being listed.

What is the best practice to filter the ICollection? Should I filter it on the `Controller` before passing it to the `View` or can I filter it on the `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best practise is in Model for view contain lists for every area

```
class ViewModel
{
   ICollection<string> ForArea1ExampleNames{get;set;}
   ICollection<string> ForArea2ExampleNames{get;set;}

   public ViewModel(ICollection<string> forArea1ExampleNames,ICollection<string> forArea2ExampleNames)
   {
      ForArea1ExampleNames = forArea1ExampleNames;
      ForArea2ExampleNames = forArea2ExampleNames;
   }

}
```

In controller

```
var forArea1ExampleNames = SomeService.GetForArea1ExampleNames()//This is 
var forArea2ExampleNames = SomeService.GetForArea2ExampleNames()// business logic
var model = new ViewModel(forArea1ExampleNames,forArea2ExampleNames);
```

Filtering filenames is a business logic.So It should be separated